# Bootstrap 6 & 6 not horizontal alligned

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Any ideas why my aligned is not correct? The text field should be on the left top side of the card.

[image]

```
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Contactgegevens</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <a href="http://www.ikzoekmark.nl" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>&nbsp; Mark Ruiter</a><br />
                  <a href="mailto:mark.ruiter@wcw.be"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i><br />
                  <a href="tel:31653403737"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>&nbsp; 31653403737</a><br />
                  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mrmarkruiter/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>&nbsp; LinkedIn</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Contactformulier</div>
                <div class="card-body">

                  <form id="contact" action="#" method="post">

                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group" id="naam_div">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="naam" name="naam" value="" placeholder="Uw naam" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" id="firma_div">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firma" name="firma" value="" placeholder="Uw firma" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" id="email_div">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Uw email adres" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group input-group" id="bericht_div">
                          <textarea name="bericht" id="bericht" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Type hier uw bericht" required>Beste Mark, graag nodig ik je uit voor een kop koffie bij ons.</textarea>
                        </div>

                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Verstuur e-mail</button>
                    </div>

                  </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your columns in the `row` class so they will align properly. Example:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">Column One</div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">Column Two</div>
</div>
```

I added a [jsfiddle with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/crazymatt/v8snpf46/2/) so you can see a working version. Hope that helps.

On a random note I noticed you forgot to add a closing `</a>` tag to this line,

`<a href="mailto:email"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i><br />`

Comment: hows is that correct they are not horizontally aligned

Comment: @nikhilsugandh not sure what you are referring too, can you clarify?